# Google Analytics Property vs. View for app vs. website

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I have a website (WordPress) that is set up at http://mydomain.com

I also have an app (meteor) that lives on a subdomain http://app.mydomain.com

I would like to track these two separately. I already have the tracking code on the WordPress site. Do I add the app as a new property or a new view?

When I tried to add the app as a separate property, in the tracking code I see this line:

```
ga('create', 'TRACKING_CODE', 'mydomain.com');
```

It seems to be that GA only cares about the top domain level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one property for mydomain.com and two views: one for http://mydomain.com and one for http://app.mydomain.com. For the two views, create a filter that includes only traffic to that domain. E.g. Include Only Hostname (whatever).

Regarding this:

```
ga('create', 'TRACKING_CODE', 'mydomain.com');
```

Leave it as is. The `mydomain.com` allows you to track across subdomains, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. So there will be 2 filters, for the website, the filter will only include `mydomain.com`, and for the app it will only include `app.mydomain.com`?

Comment: That's correct. It's best practice to create a unfiltered profile, too. So three profiles in total.

Comment: I see. And the unfiltered profile would include data for both? And do I include the same tracking info on my app?

Comment: Yeah, the unfiltered would be your 'global profile' where you'd have visibility to both your app and site. Include the same tracking info on the app. The tracking code should be identical on both.